# opcode of transfer from memory to register

Tags: x86-16, opcode, instruction-set

```
     Mov DL, [1000H]
```

This is the code and i couldn't find how to write OPCODE

it's a transfer from memory to register and it use MOV keyword so

I looked INSTRUCTION SET

and I found that  " 100010 dw oo rrr mmm disp "

so I made OPCODE in this format  " 100010 11 oo 010 mmm disp "

I couldn't decide "oo" and "mmm" part

As I know it , we write a register code to mmm part and there is no register here.

What should I write to "oo" and "mmm" part ?

Comment: Please provide a link to the INSTRUCTION SET reference you are using. There is usually a separate section that explains how to encode `r/m`. But really, the practical answer is to use an assembler. Hand-assembling code is an interesting exercise, but it is not practical because it is error-prone, time-consuming, and needs to repeated any time you change your code: Exactly the sort of thing that computers are great at. The program to do this is called an assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov dl,[1000h]  ; -> 100010 11 oo 010 mmm disp
```

Your opcode encoding mistakenly addresses the DX register.
The correct encoding is 10001010b, 0001_0110b, 0000_0000b, 0001_0000b
So the mod field is 00b and the r/m field is 110b